# HTTP 502 - Trying to write response body while the handler is in an inconsistent state REQUEST_READY

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm getting a lot of 502 responses from my API:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-13 15:15:13,802] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator} -  Found resource in Cache for key: /Proxy/Temporary/1.0.0/1.0.0/AMQP/{uid}/{topic}:POST {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-13 15:15:13,802] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} -  Authenticated API, authentication response relieved: API call failed reason=API_authentication_failure transactionId=urn:uuid:159bd2ab-e1d0-4bc9-9ff1-8458a04165a5 with accessToken=Bearer f9621dbc78f8bcc4a442ab5050c26069 for requestURI=/Proxy/Temporary/1.0.0/AMQP/2d5ccea7-0280-413b-aab2-1c7bac999875/00000004 at time=Mon Feb 13 15:15:13 WET 2017 from clientIP=192.168.11.86, elapsedTimeInMilliseconds=0 {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-13 15:15:13,902] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.connections.SourceConnections} -  Shutting down connection forcefully http-incoming-1457 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.connections.SourceConnections}
TID: [] [] [2017-02-13 15:15:13,902]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Illegal incoming connection state: CLOSED . Possibly two send backs are happening for the same request {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
TID: [] [] [2017-02-13 15:15:13,903]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Trying to write response body while the handler is in an inconsistent state CLOSED {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
TID: [] [] [2017-02-13 15:15:13,904] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.connections.SourceConnections} -  Shutting down connection forcefully http-incoming-1457 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.connections.SourceConnections}
TID: [] [] [2017-02-13 15:15:13,904] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Unexpected I/O error: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureWriteOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:270)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:461)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.sendEncryptedData(SSLIOSession.java:343)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.outboundTransport(SSLIOSession.java:431)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.outputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:152)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.writable(BaseIOReactor.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:342)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [] [] [2017-02-13 15:15:13,906] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.connections.SourceConnections} -  Shutting down connection forcefully http-incoming-1457 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.connections.SourceConnections}
TID: [] [] [2017-02-13 15:15:13,906] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  http-incoming-1457: Keep-Alive connection was closed: http-incoming-1457 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
TID: [] [] [2017-02-13 15:15:13,906] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.connections.SourceConnections} -  Shutting down connection forcefully http-incoming-1457 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.connections.SourceConnections}
```

Although this looks like something is taking so long, in the majority of the cases this response comes with bellow 300ms roundtrip, sometimes, even less. More or less the same as valid responses.

My API has JavaScript sequences and the scripts are executed all the way til the end.

What am I doing wrong here?

This is my API definition:

```
<api context="/MyAPI/1.0.0" name="admin--MyAPI"
    transports="https" version="1.0.0" version-type="context">
    <resource faultSequence="fault" methods="POST" uri-template="/AMQP/{uid}/{topic}">
        <inSequence>
            <filter regex="PRODUCTION" source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE">
                <then>
                    <property
                        expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" name="api.ut.backendRequestTime"/>
                    <send>
                        <endpoint name="admin--MyAPI_APIsandboxEndpoint_1">
                            <default/>
                        </endpoint>
                    </send>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <send>
                        <endpoint name="admin--MyAPI_APIsandboxEndpoint_1">
                            <default/>
                        </endpoint>
                    </send>
                </else>
            </filter>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
    <resource faultSequence="fault" methods="DELETE" uri-template="/AMQP/{uid}">
        <inSequence>
            <filter regex="PRODUCTION" source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE">
                <then>
                    <property
                        expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" name="api.ut.backendRequestTime"/>
                    <send>
                        <endpoint name="admin--MyAPI_APIsandboxEndpoint_1">
                            <default/>
                        </endpoint>
                    </send>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <send>
                        <endpoint name="admin--MyAPI_APIsandboxEndpoint_1">
                            <default/>
                        </endpoint>
                    </send>
                </else>
            </filter>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
    <resource faultSequence="fault" methods="POST" url-mapping="/AMQP">
        <inSequence>
            <filter regex="PRODUCTION" source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE">
                <then>
                    <property
                        expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" name="api.ut.backendRequestTime"/>
                    <respond/>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <send>
                        <endpoint name="admin--MyAPI_APIsandboxEndpoint_2">
                            <default/>
                        </endpoint>
                    </send>
                </else>
            </filter>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
    <handlers>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
            <property name="apiImplementationType" value="ENDPOINT"/>
        </handler>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler"/>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler">
            <property name="policyKey" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml"/>
            <property name="policyKeyApplication" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/app-tiers.xml"/>
            <property name="id" value="A"/>
            <property name="policyKeyResource" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/res-tiers.xml"/>
        </handler>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler"/>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtGoogleAnalyticsTrackingHandler">
            <property name="configKey" value="gov:/apimgt/statistics/ga-config.xml"/>
        </handler>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler"/>
    </handlers>
</api>
```

This is my sequence definition:

```
<sequence name="admin--MyAPI:v1.0.0--In">
    <property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
    <switch
        source="concat(get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_METHOD'), '-', get-property('axis2', 'REST_URL_POSTFIX'))" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
        <case regex="^POST-/AMQP$">
            <script language="js">
            // code that executes without errors
            </script>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
            <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2"/>
            <respond/>
        </case>
        <case regex="^DELETE-/AMQP/[^/]+$">
            <script language="js">
            // code that executes without errors
            </script>
            <respond/>
        </case>
        <case regex="^POST-/AMQP/[^/]+.*">
            <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="payload"/>
            <property
                expression="get-property('axis2', 'ContentType')" name="ContentType"/>
            <property
                expression="get-property('axis2', 'REST_URL_POSTFIX')" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX"/>
            <property
                expression="get-property('axis2', 'TRANSPORT_HEADERS')" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS"/>
            <script language="js">
            // code that executes without errors
            </script>
            <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2"
                type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <property name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" value="202"/><!-- otherwise won't always be 202 -->
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <respond/>
        </case>
        <default/>
    </switch>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Please post your API synapse file and other custom sequences if you have any.

Comment: @Bhathiya, I've added the API and sequence definitions to the question.

Comment: Could you please explain the flow? I'm confused about the `<respond/>` mediator.

Comment: The `<respond/>` is because I'm doing everything I need there and I'm not forwarding the request to another endpoint. It's a default endpoint type.